# How to handle Rails joins table relationship removals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, routes, applicationcontroller

I am creating an application which manages Users and Tasks. The relationship between these two models is many-to-many, as a user can have many tasks assigned to them, and a task can have many users assigned to it. For this reason, I created a UserTasks migration and model to serve as a joins table. Looking into the future, I realized I want my frontend functionality to give a user the ability to assign and remove users from a given task. Since I am using a JS frontend, and sending AJAX requests to my rails server controllers, I am not clear on how to handle this functionality. I do not want to remove the user nor the task from the database, but simply the relationship. Is it ok to make an API controller for my UserTask model, and handle this logic in a #destroy method? Is there a more automated approach that Rails provides?

Here's what my models look like:

User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

  after_initialize :ensure_session_token

  validate :valid_email

  validates :name, :email, :password_digest, :session_token, presence: true
  validates :email, :session_token, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, allow_nil: true }

  has_many :user_tasks,
  foreign_key: :user_id,
  class_name: "UserTask"

  has_many :tasks,
  through: :user_tasks,
  source: :task

  ...misc code
end
```

Task

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :user_tasks,
  foreign_key: :task_id,
  class_name: "UserTask"

  has_many :assignees,
  through: :user_tasks,
  source: :user

  has_many :sub_tasks,
  foreign_key: :parent_task_id,
  class_name: "Task"
end
```

UserTask

```
class UserTask < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, :task_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user,
  foreign_key: :user_id,
  class_name: "User"

  belongs_to :task,
  foreign_key: :task_id,
  class_name: "Task"
end
```

Current Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#root'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    resources :users, only: [:create, :update, :show]
    resources :tasks, only: [:create, :index, :show, :update, :destroy]
    resources :projects, only: [:create, :index, :show, :update, :destroy]
    resource :session, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Comment: I would prefer to create a separate controller for `UserTasksController` when there is more logic to do with it, like including other columns in that table that might be updated like what a user has achieved for a task or what is his hour rate for this task, ...etc.

Otherwise I will create a descriptive endpoint in either the `UsersController` or `TasksController` to achieve the job.

Comment: Considering that I only care about the removal of the relation, I guess doing it in the TasksController would be the most semantic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides ability to manage `:has_many` records through parent record.

For example you can allow User to accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_tasks with allow_destroy: true option.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for : user_tasks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

After such config you can add/destroy nested attributes through User record `update` action.

```
params = {
  id: 'user_id', user_tasks_attributes: [
    { user_id: 'user_id', task_id: 'task_id' }, #this will create new join record
    { id: 'user_task_id', _destroy: '1' } #this will destroy join record
  ]
}
```

But I'd create a **separate** controller for UserTasks

Read [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for more information.